# pandas dataframes, .ix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

`df` is a dataframe for stock prices over a range of dates. df.shape is (367,1709).The rows are timestamps for dates and the columns are stock symbols. The timestamps range from 02.04.2012 to 27.09.2013.

I run a for loop as follows:

```
 ldt_timestamps=df.index
 symbols = df.columns
 for sym in symbols:
    for i in range(1, len(ldt_timestamps)) # looping from 2nd row to calculate ratio of today's price and yesterdays price
        f_symprice_today = df[sym].ix[ldt_timestamps[i]]
```

The problem is that the loop runs into an error 'KeyError- Timestamp: 2012-04-03 00:00:00. I tracked the error and found that it occurs when the loop reaches a specific stock symbol column - "M50". This is the 891st column

I have tried the following:

1. Checked if it is the timestamp that is causing the error, i checked df['M50'].ix[ldt_timestamps[200]]. The error is the same (albeit with a different timestamp).
2. Checked if the stock symbol that is causing the error.  I tried using other symbols. No error. Even if i tried symbols occurring after "M50", there was no error. So the problem was the symbol. But the symbols are taken from the columns of the dataframe.
3. To further understand the error, i tried df['M50'].shape, it returns (0,1709). This is funny becuae when I try this with other stock symbol, the shape is always (367,)

df.T.Head shows the following:

```
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  Index: 5 entries, 20MICRONS to AANJANEYA
  Columns: 367 entries, 2012-04-02 00:00:00 to 2013-09-27 00:00:00
  dtypes: float64(367)
```

the df written to csv looks like the following:

```
date      20MICRONS 3IINFOTECH  3MINDIA A2ZMES  AANJANEYA   AARTIDRUGS
4/2/2012    83.85   16.15   3761.25 116.75  560.7   104.4
4/3/2012    83.75   16.1    3997.65 125.95  553 103
4/4/2012    81.75   16.05   3992.3  122.55  552.25  104.55
4/9/2012    81.55   15.7    4176.45 118.05  522.2   103.65
4/10/2012   83.05   15.75   4234.1  118.85  523.8   105.5
4/11/2012   81.75   15.85   4238.6  115.95  510.9   108.2
4/12/2012   81.6    15.9    4371.75 114.5   529 109.9
4/13/2012   81.85   15.5    4403.4  112.55  514.7   112.1
4/16/2012   80.7    15.5    4449.65 112.95  509.9   111.9
```

really at my wits end on this one. Request for help in how to find out what is causing this error for just one stock symbol.

Comment: Can you show `df.T.head()`?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 5 entries, 20MICRONS to AANJANEYA
Columns: 367 entries, 2012-04-02 00:00:00 to 2013-09-27 00:00:00
dtypes: float64(367)

Comment: Really what I meant is just show some of the raw data that's relevant to your question.

Comment: Apologies. not sure how to show the raw data. Have edited the question to show part of the csv file written from df.

Comment: Have you put in print statements etc. to examime what values you iterators are taking? That can help to find the error.

Comment: Also, I hope this is not a dumb suggestion, but the pct_change() method might be an easier way to get at the type of information you want.

Comment: Can you post a link to the file?